# Resume polling after 286

Tags: javascript, html, htmx

Making a small game with HTMX and Go. I'm having HTMX poll the server and updating the state of the game every 1 second or on user input

```html
<div class="game" hx-post="/tick" hx-trigger="every 1s, keydown[ (some keys here) ] from:body">
    {{ block "state" . }}
    <!-- state -->
    {{ end }}
</div>
```

When the game ends, I send 286 status code to stop the polling of "every" trigger, as mentioned [here](https://htmx.org/docs/#polling).

The user is given the option to restart the game, how can I resume the polling?

Note that moving the div inside the state block is not an option, because then user inputs reset the 1 second timer.

Is there another status code that can be sent? or even some custom JS to restart the polling?

Comment: Wouldn't it restart if you reload the whole `div.game`? E.g. your restart button could look like `<button hx-get="/new-game" hx-trigger="click" hx-target=".game" hx-swap="outerHTML">Restart</button>` and `/new-game` endpoint  should return something like `<div class="game" ...></div>`.

Comment: There is indeed a way to solve it but it requires multiple extra divs (and maybe an extra server endpoint), which I highly dislike. I'm looking for either a one-liner from the Go/server side or even a JS function.

Comment: Well, you don't need any extra divs in that approach, but you need to have endpoint returning your game field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### HTMX way

Restart button could reload the whole `<div class="game"..>`. For example, I've defined `/new-game` endpoint returning the game field:

```
<div class="game" hx-post="/tick" hx-trigger="every 1s, keydown[ (some keys here) ] from:body">
</div>
```

and the restart button looks like:

```
<button hx-get="/new-game" hx-trigger="click" hx-target=".game" hx-swap="outerHTML">Restart</button>
```

Since we're using `hx-swap="outerHTML"` it will replace the whole element and HTMX will start handling it from scratch.

### Pure JavaScript

You also have an option to do the same with pure JavaScript by recreating `div.game` and calling `htmx.process('.game')` to set it up.

Just calling `htmx.process` on the already processed element doesn't work. So you have to create a new one, as an easy option you could leverage [node.cloneNode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) API.

```
function restartGame() {
    const game = htmx.find('.game');
    const clone = game.cloneNode();

    game.parentNode.insertBefore(clone, game);
    htmx.remove(game);
    htmx.process('.game');
}
```

```
<button onclick="restartGame()">Restart</button>
```